# Adding Css into NVelocity FormHelper

Tags: css, castle, nvelocity

Is it possible to add css into FormHelper in NVelocity ??? For example i wish to add css into FormHelper.TextField() . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Castle Project Docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/MonoRail.FormHelper.ashx?HL=textfield#TextField_9).

#### Documentation

```
$Form.TextField(target[, attributes])
```

#### Example

```
$Form.TextField("data.Id", "%{value = 'someId', style='width: 110px; height: 90px;'}"
```